# Attributes vs. CustomAttributes in PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've been working with Reflections and wanted to get all the attributes declared for a property. There are two properties under [`PropertInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.PropertyInfo_properties.aspx) class which are [`CustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254.aspx) and [`Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.Attributes%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true).

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/), they are explained as follows:

**Attributes:**

> This property represents the attributes associated with a member. All
>   members have a set of attributes that are defined in relation to the
>   specific type of member. The property attributes let the user know if
>   this property is the default property, a SpecialName property, and so
>   on.

**Note:** The code sample given in the [`PropertyInfo.Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.attributes.aspx) page doesn't even work.

**Custom Attributes:**

> An array that contains all the custom attributes applied to this
>   member, or an array with zero elements if no attributes are defined.

However, when I run this code for them, `Attributes` returns nothing while `CustomAttributes` returns [`Required`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx).

```
void Main()
{
    var attributes = typeof(Myproperty).GetProperty("Caption").CustomAttributes;
    //var attributes = typeof(Myproperty).GetProperty("Caption").Attributes;
    attributes.Dump(); //Dump is a LinqPad method which dumps everything to the outpu window
}

public class Myproperty
{
    private string caption = "Default caption";

    [Required]
    public string Caption
    {
        get{return caption;}
        set {if(caption!=value) {caption = value;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically they're slightly different meanings of the word "attribute" here. It sounds like you do want CustomAttributes.

Comment: I've figured that what I wanted is `CustomAttributes` but can you please explain what the difference is? IMO it seems it doesn't do what its name implies.

Comment: Basically, see the answer from Hans. They're very different things. Look at MethodInfo.Attributes for an example which may make more sense to you - it's more like the modifiers that can be applied to a property / method / etc.

Comment: See static [methods of `System.Attribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute#methods) if you want to discover even inherited attributes.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

PropertyInfo.Attributes doesn't have anything to do with the Attribute class.  Check the [PropertyAttributes enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyattributes.aspx) for values you may encounter.  These are CLR implementation details that have no obvious connection to C# code.  Yes, that was an unfortunate naming choice.

To find attributes like your [Required] attribute you must use the CustomAttributes property.